# Any flag that allows you to use all cores across multiple locales

Tags: chapel

I am testing my Matrix multiplication using a forall loop. I have noticed that across my two Locales that it is only ever using 7 cores out of the 8. Is there any Chapel flag that would allow me to specify how many cores to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forall loops in Chapel should use all available cores by default, as long as the number of iterations exceeds the number of cores.  What technique are you using to determine that only 7 cores are being used?  What is the loop you are executing?

One thing that can be useful to verify that Chapel knows about all your cores (i.e., isn't misconfigured) is to execute `writeln(here.numPUs());` which will print out the number of cores ("processing units" or "PUs") available on your given locale.  numPUs() is documented [as part of the interface supported on the `locale` type](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/locales.html?highlight=numpus).  To check the cores for all locales, you could write something like:

```
coforall loc in Locales do
  on loc do
    writeln(here.numPUs());
```

To your specific question, there are some things you can use to alter the number of tasks used by most forall loops or by the runtime itself, though again, these shouldn't be necessary in general to ensure that 8/8 cores are being used.

There's a general config [`dataParTasksPerLocale`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/usingchapel/executing.html#controlling-degree-of-data-parallelism) that tells most standard iterators how many tasks to use per locale to implement a forall loop.  There's also an environment variable named [CHPL_RT_NUM_THREADS_PER_LOCALE](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/usingchapel/executing.html#environment-variable-control-over-chapel-behavior) that can be used to change the number of threads used by the runtime to execute tasks.

But again, if Chapel has correctly detected that your system has 8 cores (as verified by numPUs()), both of these variables should default to 8 as well.

Comment: ahhh okay, When I htop during the run it shows 4 are used on the first board and only 3 on the second board.

Comment: OK thanks, that sounds like a bug to me.  Would you consider filing an issue on the Chapel GitHub board with a simple example that illustrates what you are doing and what you're observing?

Comment: Also, since you noted that you were seeing this when using multiple locales, I've updated the here.numPUs() text above to include a code sample that checks all of the locales.